# Change target framework from .net framework to .net core in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

What seems to be straightforward sometimes is not.
What I want to do is simple change of target framework from .NET Framework 4.6.1 to .NET Core 2.2 (Or later).  The drop down list in the Application tab (you can get to here by right-clicking the Project file in the VS2019 and click properties) doesn't provide .net core versions as options.

The project Application tab shows following properties:

Target framework:  .NET Framework 4.6.1
Output type: Console Application

Comment: It isn't so easy to change the .NET Framework version from 4.x to core because .net core is a complete new implementation. You have to migrate your application: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/